# nativescript 6.0.1 can't run/prepare android application

Tags: webpack, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I recently updated `tns` to version 6.0.1, which I have read always uses `webpack` to build projects.

I used `tns migrate` on my project, updated my local plugin to AndroidX (with Android Studio refactor option), generated my `.aar` file and used `tns migrate` on my plugin demo project. After that, when I try the demo project, it does work. My problem is on my main project: I added the new plugin to my project, removed and added android platform (`tns-android` version 6.0.0), but when I run `tns prepare android` or `tns run android` I get this error concerning my plugin:

```sh
ERROR in /workspace/workspace-nativescript/nativescript-my-plugin/src/my-plugin.ts
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /workspace/workspace-nativescript/nativescript-my-plugin/src/my-plugin.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at NativeScriptAngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/workspace/workspace-nativescript/my-project/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:844:23)
    at NativeScriptAngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/workspace/workspace-nativescript/my-project/node_modules/nativescript-dev-webpack/plugins/NativeScriptAngularCompilerPlugin.js:28:26)
    at plugin.done.then (/workspace/workspace-nativescript/my-project/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I was reading there were issues like this before regarding `nativescript-dev-webpack`, but I have version 1.0.1 from the `tns migrate` which is the last. Also here is my `tnsconfig.json` file (I also have a `nsconfig.json` file, but it's empty):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "es2015.iterable"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": [
                "app/*"
            ],
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
                "./node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have `nativescript-my-plugin/src/my-plugin.ts` file in your project? Or it's platform specific files like `nativescript-my-plugin/src/my-plugin.[ios|android].ts`?

Comment: @Manoj I don't have the `src/my-plugin.ts` file, but I have the `android/ios` ones. I supposed this file is generated or referenced to the platform while doing the bundle, cause the demo project also tries to find it but does not show any error. Just in case, my `package.json` file imports the plugin this way `"my-plugin": "file:<local_path_to_plugin>/src"`

Comment: That sounds similar to the [issue here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/issues/625), try removing the platform specific files and have one `my-plugin.ts` file and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you've linked a TypeScript plugin in your main Angular app (instead of installing it from tgz).

I suppose your plugin is already created from the official plugins seed and that's the reason the demo app is properly configured or you are running a TypeScript Demo, not an Angular one.

When you want to link a plugin in your Angular app, you have to include it's TypeScript files (as far as I know, it's a limitation of the `AngularCompilerPlugin`). This is already configured in your demo apps if you start from the plugins seed (`tns plugin create`).

In other words, open `tsconfig.json` in your main app (`/workspace/workspace-nativescript/my-project/tsconfig.json`) and replace its content with:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "es2015.iterable"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": [
                "app/*"
            ],
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
                "./node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "../nativescript-my-plugin/src",
        "**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "../nativescript-my-plugin/src/node_modules",
        "node_modules",
        "platforms"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I did what you said and I got some warnings:  `hooks/after-prepare/nativescript-dev-version.js will NOT be executed because it has invalid arguments - $usbLiveSyncService.` - `hooks/after-prepare/nativescript-nodeify.js will NOT be executed because it has invalid arguments - $platformsData.
` and this error `**ERROR**  TypeError: Cannot read property 'ViewCompat' of undefined`. I'm not sure if this error is part of the plugin or something else, so I will mark this as the right answer for now.

Comment: @amlibtest I'm going through a similar process/problem at the moment. Did you solve your issue with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ViewCompat' of undefined` by chance?

Comment: It looks like the version of these plugins (nativescript-dev-version and nativescript-nodeify)  are not compatible with nativescript@6.0. I suggest you take a look at their GitHub issues section.

Comment: @N.J.Dawson for the ViewCompat issue, see the answer I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597342/n-nativescript-6-typeerror-cannot-read-property-viewcompat-of-undefined/57597343#57597343