# {N} Nativescript 6 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'ViewCompat' of undefined

Tags: android, nativescript

After updating from NS 5 to NS 6, I got the following error when trying to run my application on Android:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ViewCompat' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 5):

This turned out to be a problem in a plugin I was using that needed to be updated to use the AndroidX support library. I found it by searching my plugins for the string 'ViewCompat' - you should see a reference to AndroidX rather than android.support. Specifically, I resolved my issue by updating from an older version of nativescript-loading-indicator to @nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator.